# RIAK node does not start

Tags: riak

I'm trying to use RIAK, which I installed (version 2.2.0 for Erlang R16B01). But when I try to start a node, via:

```
sudo dev/dev2/bin/riak start
```

It respond with:

```
!!!!
!!!! WARNING: ulimit -n is 1024; 65536 is the recommended minimum.
!!!!
riak failed to start within 15 seconds,
see the output of 'riak console' for more information.
If you want to wait longer, set the environment variable
WAIT_FOR_ERLANG to the number of seconds to wait.
```

The console however says (in summary):

```
config is OK
-config /home/steven/riak-2.2.0/dev/dev2/data/generated.configs/app.2017.03.08.19.41.06.config -args_file /home/steven/riak-2.2.0/dev/dev2/data/generated.configs/vm.2017.03.08.19.41.06.args -vm_args /home/steven/riak-2.2.0/dev/dev2/data/generated.configs/vm.2017.03.08.19.41.06.args
!!!!
!!!! WARNING: ulimit -n is 1024; 65536 is the recommended minimum.
!!!!
Exec:  /home/steven/riak-2.2.0/dev/dev2/bin/../erts-5.10.2/bin/erlexec -boot /home/steven/riak-2.2.0/dev/dev2/bin/../releases/2.2.0/riak               -config /home/steven/riak-2.2.0/dev/dev2/data/generated.configs/app.2017.03.08.19.41.06.config -args_file /home/steven/riak-2.2.0/dev/dev2/data/generated.configs/vm.2017.03.08.19.41.06.args -vm_args /home/steven/riak-2.2.0/dev/dev2/data/generated.configs/vm.2017.03.08.19.41.06.args              -pa /home/steven/riak-2.2.0/dev/dev2/bin/../lib/basho-patches -- console
Root: /home/steven/riak-2.2.0/dev/dev2/bin/..
Usage: beam.smp [flags] [ -- [init_args] ]
The flags are: ...
```

Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: see the output of 'riak console' for more information

Comment: I added the output

Comment: 'config is OK' is only the first line, and is printed before the startup script actually tries to start Riak.  Is nothing else output?

Comment: I didn't realized there was something meaningfull in it. I updated it again!

Comment: The 'Exec' line looks a valid command, but the 'Usage' response implies that beam.smp rejected something.  Are you using the patched version of Erlang available from http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.2.0/setup/installing/source/erlang/ ? If so, you may need to recompile.

Comment: It works after recompiling! Thanks a ton!